# Exclude the_post_thumbnail from gallery shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this code to have a simple gallery on the page:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery itemtag="ul" icontag="li" size="full" columns="0" link="file" ]'); ?>
```

The problem now is that the end-user has to upload an image via the Media page before selecting this image as featured image.

I know this could be solved by adding the featured image's ID to the shortcode's exclude list, but how to get this ID automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function exclude_thumbnail_from_gallery($null, $attr)
{
    if (!$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id())
        return $null; // no point carrying on if no thumbnail ID

    // temporarily remove the filter, otherwise endless loop!
    remove_filter('post_gallery', 'exclude_thumbnail_from_gallery');

    // pop in our excluded thumbnail
    if (!isset($attr['exclude']) || empty($attr['exclude']))
        $attr['exclude'] = array($thumbnail_ID);
    elseif (is_array($attr['exclude']))
        $attr['exclude'][] = $thumbnail_ID;

    // now manually invoke the shortcode handler
    $gallery = gallery_shortcode($attr);

    // add the filter back
    add_filter('post_gallery', 'exclude_thumbnail_from_gallery', 10, 2);

    // return output to the calling instance of gallery_shortcode()
    return $gallery;
}
add_filter('post_gallery', 'exclude_thumbnail_from_gallery', 10, 2);
```

Comment: At first i thought it was working like a charm, but I just found out that it excludes all of my images and returns a value 'Array'.

Comment: My bad - completely misread the filter in `gallery_shortcode()` - check revised answer!

Comment: Another approach would be using the `shortcode_atts_gallery` filter introduced in WP 3.6. It allows to change all attributes – and therefore the passed IDs – without much hassle. See: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/wordpress-36-shortcode-attribute-filter/ and https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L332

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php  $id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery exclude='.$id.' link="file" itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" size="thumbnail" columns="4" ]'); ?>
```

Comment: Much useful if you want to automatically add a gallery to each post. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, and don't use $id as a temp variable, you'll get strange bugs. $thumbnail_id should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery exclude="' . get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) . '"]');
```