# Wordpress page not showing with correct template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new page and allocated to default template which is same as other pages but it shows up with broken template with comment (which I want to remove from this page) in it and I cannot find where it's coming from i the actual template folder. I have searched page.php and others but had no luck.

The settings are exactly the same as other pages and I have no idea why it's doing this.

Is there somewhere I can check to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable comments, you can do that within the page editor in the backend. It should be below the content area.

Regarding setting a page template, If multiple page templates are available for you to use, you choose which page template each page uses on the right side of the page editor underneath the Publishing options.

Comment: Whenever I put featured image it gets allocated to attachment.php and then loop-attachment.php is there a way we can change this?

Comment: I think [this StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337999/wordpress-exclude-the-post-thumbnail-from-gallery-shortcode) would help you quite a bit.