# Remove featured image from showing on product display page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wooCommerce and Wordpress.
When you set the featured image for a woocommerce product, it shows up as the first/main image in the gallery on the product details page. I don't want this. I simply want to hide/remove the featured image entirely from the product details page. I want the featured image to only show up in the product category page but not on a single product detail page. 
I tried removing the image with the code 
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );`
in theme functions file.
Still unable to see desired results.

I'm using the theme [room09](http://elementsmart.com/product/rock-sunglasses-2/).

I want to hide this vertical image (have set it featured image) from showing on this page only.

```
<div class="images">

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        $image              = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
        $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $attachment_count   = count( get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) ) );

        if ( $attachment_count != 1 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you buy the theme with the woocommerce installed already? Or add it as a plugin after installing the theme?

Comment: i added theme after installing woocommerce .........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this without editing any of the theme files, just add this to a plugin or functions.php in a child theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 3);

function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id, $post_id) {
    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    if ($attachment_id != $featured_image) {
        return $html;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code? What does 10 and 3 refer to here?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal the 10 and 3 are used by the add_filter function. 10 being what order in which this is called, since you can have multiple functions via the same filter and 3 is the number of variables passed since the default is one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the single product image function. I dont know if you have the same plugin as me.

You can block quote the add_action for this on line 93 of woocommerce-hooks.php, it should be in the root directory of plugin folder or in yourtheme/woocommerce/...

```
//add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

It should remove it, if it doesn't then do this:

Blockquote or remove line 31 in content-single-product.php:

```
//do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
```

**Edit**

Rather add a display:none in CSS for the featured image. Go to Appearance - Editor and add this:

CSS:

```
.yith_magnifier_zoom_wrap{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: hey i commented line in content-single-product.php . but that removed all of my images. i merely need to remove featured image. kindly check the page.

Comment: So you want to do what exactly.. Remove just the big image and keep the other images for the product?

Comment: i want it to show on all other pages (widgets and category page etc) but not on the product display page.

Comment: Please put that in your question in future.Add back the do_action but in the hooks file, swap 'woocommerce_show_product_images' with the 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails'.

Comment: Try the above, so we can see what you get

Comment: i interchanged both values in hooks file but now the page is crashing.... not displaying at all.

Comment: Ok sorry add it back please! I'm trying to find a fix

Comment: just found this page http://www.skyverge.com/blog/hide-woocommerce-product-image/ even then its not happening. hope it can help.

Comment: You did try that remove_action already and it didn't work. So lets use CSS for this. Please see my edit.

Comment: but css is removing the magnifier altogether ......... i need the magnifier .... only one image needs to be gone ...... http://www.skyverge.com/blog/hide-woocommerce-product-image/#comment-448 this comment is showing it can be done ........

Comment: i found to more links http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/4286  2nd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337999/wordpress-exclude-the-post-thumbnail-from-gallery-shortcode m working on them now ...... kindly see if they look okay to you

Comment: So you want to magnify those small thumbnail images?

Comment: Maybe change the add_action to remove_action for the ( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it. For someone facing similar problem, add this code to the functions file of your theme:

```
if ( ! empty( $attachment_ids ) ) array_unshift( $attachment_ids, get_post_thumbnail_id() );

if ( empty( $attachment_ids ) ) return;
```

It may depend on the theme you are using. Make necessary changes to the code.

Comment: Does this still work with the current version of WooCommerce? Any words of advice for someone currently struggling with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added both these snippets in my `functions.php` to remove the badge and featured image from the shop page loop.

```
// Remove product images from the shop loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

// Remove sale badges from the shop loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
```