# Exclude featured image from product page Wordpress and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What needs to be done is that the featured image would only appear in the catalog view, but not in a single product view. So basically if an image is set as a featured image it should not be shown as the main image in product page and in should be excluded from thumbnails as well.

I have been looking ofr solution for a long time and tried different many approaches but nothing seems to help:

I have been adding the following to the `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

as well as all of the solutions in here: [Remove featured image from showing on product display page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278291)

Theme is Mr. Tailor

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this solution like you, and found that your code is almost functioning. Only had to change the number on the second line from 20 to 3, and it's working.

So the code is:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 3 );
```

This will remove featured image in the product page and replaces it with the first thumbnail.